# How to parse time from String to Date object?

Tags: java

I have a code which parses String time to date object. But, when the time in String is in format of HH:mm:ss eg. 23:34:45, the date object, after parsing, changes it to some different time.  I have used timezone, but couldn't find a way to retain the time as original. How can i do this?
These attributes are giving wrong values: 
timeLine, timeSystem, timeGapDate

```
            timeFromLine = getTimeFromLine(line);
            timeFromSystem= getSystemTime();

            timeGap= propertiesReader.getPropertyValue("timeGap");
            sf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            sf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

            //sf1.setLenient(false);
            timeLine= sf1.parse(timeFromLine);
            timeSystem=sf1.parse(timeFromSystem);
            timeGapDate=sf1.parse(timeGap);
            startTimeLong=timeSystem.getTime();
            timeGapLong=timeGapDate.getTime();
            endTimeLong=startTimeLong-timeGapLong;
            Date d= new Date(endTimeLong);
            endTimeString= sf1.format(d);
            endTimeDate1=sf1.parse(endTimeString);
```

Method- getSystemTime();

```
private static String getSystemTime() {
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");//dd/MM/yyyy
Date now = new Date();
String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
return strDate;
}
```

Method getTimeFromLine();

```
private static String getTimeFromLine(String s){
final Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
String date2 ="";

while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    final String line2 = sc.nextLine();
    String[] number = line2.split(Constants.NUMBER_REGEX);
    String firstSplitValue3= number[3];
    date2=firstSplitValue3;

}
sc.close();
return date2;

}
}
```

time gap is just 00:06:00
The output I am getting is this,

timeFromLine- 23:59:15
timeFromSystem- 12:41:51
timeLine- Fri Jan 02 05:29:15 IST 1970
timeSystem- Thu Jan 01 18:11:51 IST 1970
timeGapDate- Thu Jan 01 05:36:00 IST 1970

But I want the output to be 
timeLine- 23:59:15
timeSystem- 12:41:51
timeGapDate- 00:06:00

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html

Comment: Can you narrow this down to the piece of code that's giving the problem?  There's lots of stuff here that's nothing to do with date formatting.

Comment: A short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem (but nothing else) would really help. Include sample input and output, and expected output. Additionally, please indent your code (with spaces) - it's really hard to read at the moment.

Comment: I have edited my code. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Where is `timeGap` coming from?  What's in the `propertiesReader`?

Comment: Yup its in properties file. timeGap=00:06:00

Comment: So why are you converting _that_ to a `Date`? It's an amount of time; it's nothing like a `Date`.

Comment: Also, where you're showing your dates in your output, it looks like you're not using the `SimpleDateFormat` that you created.  So you're parsing in GMT, but outputting in IST.  That's why `23:59:15 GMT` is shown as `05:29:15 IST`.

Comment: So, Is there a way by which we can parse current String date as original date?

Comment: If by "original date" you mean "date in the current time zone", then sure, just remove that line that says `sf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` so that you're parsing and outputting in the same time zone.

Comment: I didn't mean that. See this is a line from my log file. **INFO: Jul 06 23:59:15 Speedo: 3,182,420K of 4,054,528K - 872,107K free, 5,847epm, 1 buffered, 223 threads, 61.3% CPU, permgen 173,731K of 262,144K - 88,412K free** . I need to parse the time from line in date format. Then I need to take the system time and subtract one hour from the system time. Then I need to grab the lines which are in between the system time and the result of the subtraction. So that i would have a one hour data. for this i am paring time from each line and comparing.

Comment: The below answer is accepted but there is a condition which @laune is talking about. If you have a better solution please go ahead sir. I am in urgent necessity.

Comment: So, are the times in the log file in GMT or in IST?  And if they're in IST, then why are you setting the `SimpleDateFormat` to GMT?

Comment: the server which generates the log file is in brisbane. And I have to write code based on their timezone.

Comment: So you really wanted to use AEST, not GMT?  Or are the times logged in GMT?

Comment: Its Australia time... Yes, but for testing purposes, I need to use GMT. We have a testing server which generates the same log file. Isn't there a universal or default timezone. Or cant we have timezone in properties file?

Comment: @DavidWallace I cant post the whole code here. Its very big. My requirement is , I have a server which generates live data and writes to a log file. I need to grab the last hour data, zip it and mail it. Like if the system time is 8 o'clock in morning, then I should get data from 7 to 8

Comment: Of course you can put the timezone in the properties file.  This is probably a better option than hardcoding GMT as the time zone, especially if your eventual plan is to run this on a log file with times in AEST.

Comment: @DavidWallace I cant post the whole code here. Its very big. My requirement is , I have a server which generates live data and writes to a log file. I need to grab the last hour data, zip it and mail it. Like if the system time is 8 o'clock in morning, then I should get data from 7 to 8. If you can provide a better solution, it would be great. I am just have one year experience . I don't know much. Please suggest sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String timeFromSystem = getSystemTime();    // your method, unchanged
Date timeSystem = sf1.parse(timeFromSystem);
System.out.println( timeFromSystem + " => " + timeSystem );
```

Result:

```
09:19:38 => Thu Jan 01 09:19:38 CET 1970
```

I don't believe that `getTimeFromLine(String s)` is correct, not without seeing the regex and an explanation why you need a loop to input a single line.

**Later**

```
public static long gapInMillis( String gap ){
    String[] hms = gap.split( ":" );
    return ((Integer.valueOf( hms[0] ) * 60 +
             Integer.valueOf( hms[1] )) * 60 +
             Integer.valueOf( hms[2] )) * 1000;
}

public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    Date now = new Date();
    Date nowMinusGap = new Date( now.getTime() - gapInMillis( gap ) );
    System.out.println( nowMinusGap + " - " + now );
}
```

This is simple and straightforward. - Not sure what the lines from standard input should do, code is too obfuscated.

**Still Later**

```
String line = "Jul 06 23:59:15";  // add currrent year and modify format
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss");
Date timeFromLine = sdf.parse( line );
System.out.println( "line: " + timeFromLine );
```

This will parse a Date from a section from the input lines you have, but the resulting day will be in year 1970. You can add the current year, but there's Dec 31/Jan 1 to consider.

This is dangerous:

```
String line = (now.getYear()+1900) + " " + "Jul 27 12:50:15";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

if( timeFromLine.after( nowMinusGap ) &&
    timeFromLine.before( now ) ){
    System.out.println( "line: " + timeFromLine + " in range" );
}
```

**Handle Dec 31/Jan 1**

Some test data and a getLine:

```
static String[] lines = new String[]{
    "Dec 31 19:50:15 ---",
    "Dec 31 21:50:15 ---",
    "Dec 31 23:50:15 ---",
    "Jan 1 00:50:15 ---",
    "Jan 1 01:50:15 ---" };
static int pos = 0;
static String getLine(){
return pos < lines.length ? lines[pos++] : null;
}
```

And the procedure filtering the lines: **Note the fake setting of now**

```
static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");
static void selectLines() throws ParseException {
    Date now = new Date();
    now = sdf.parse( "2014 Jan 1 02:00:00" ); // fake, just for testing
    Date nowMinusGap = new Date( now.getTime() - gapInMillis( gap ) );
    System.out.println( nowMinusGap + " - " + now );

    String line;
    while( (line = getLine()) != null ){
        Date timeFromLine = null;
        for( int year = now.getYear()+1900; year > 2000; year-- ){
            String lineToParse = year + " " + line;
            timeFromLine = sdf.parse( lineToParse );
            if( timeFromLine.before( now ) ) break;
        }
        System.out.println( "line: " + timeFromLine );
        if( timeFromLine.after( nowMinusGap ) &&
            timeFromLine.before( now ) ){
            System.out.println( "line: " + timeFromLine + " in range" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct @laune , but when I use getTime() method, for some values the time in long comes in negative values. For avoiding that i implemented the timezone line. Please suggest what should I do.

    `startTimeLong=timeSystem.getTime();
     timeGapLong=timeGapDate.getTime();
    `

Comment: @user3859736 Maybe you state what you want to do rather than some code where it is difficult to see what it does. Looks like you want to compute a time that is so many hours and minutes and seconds later than a time HH:mm:ss entered from System.in, but I may be wrong. Is the current date/time involved in any way?

Comment: I have a current system time. And the time from the method getTimeFromLine() . The time gap is timeGapDate(). 
Now I need to subtract timeGapDate from system time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the purpose of getTimeFromLine()?

Comment: I want to get all the lines between the system time and the value which I will get from subtracting timeGapDate from system time.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @laune. The method getTimeFromLine(String s) is parsing this line ** INFO: Jul 06 23:59:15 Speedo: 3,182,420K of 4,054,528K - 872,107K free, 5,847epm, 1 buffered, 223 threads, 61.3% CPU, permgen 173,731K of 262,144K - 88,412K free ** to get the time. Is there a different method, because as soon as I get the String time from here and parse it through date object it changes the date. Please help..

Comment: Of course: if you extract and parse just "23:59:15", it'll be on 1970-01-01. You can include "Jul 06", but the year is still missing - it will be 1970. - You can prefix the current year and parse it all, but what happens around New Year? - See addition to answer.

Comment: Okay, But when I execute this line `if(timeFromLine1.before(now)&&timeFromLine1.after(nowMinusGap)) {writer.println(line);}` Its doesn't compare the dates. It outputs false. And doesn't write anything to write.print(line). Or is there a timeZone we can add or so?

Comment: What did you do? Prefix with the current year and modified the date format?

Comment: Anyway, I've added code that's ok except for an interval spanning Dec 24 midnight.

Comment: Its working fine, but please explain what will happen on a new year. Because it is a part of project which will run for years. Please help sir. I need to explain this to my project manager.

Comment: Sure, it can be made watertight. But I'd have to be very certain about the requirements before I make a statement, and SO is not the place for lengthy discussions (short comment length, for one thing). You might set up a throw-away email address and post it here.

Comment: I made this account just for this purpose. Please open this gmail account : singhrs99568@gmail.com 
Password: singhrahul123
Go to the draft section. there you will find the full code to my project. Please suggest if more suggestions are required.

Comment: That is a clear violation of Google's terms of use.  If you want to share code, post it in your question.  But it's really better if you don't.  You should really only give us the minimum amount of code that's needed to answer your question.

Comment: @DavidWallace I cant post the whole code here. Its very big. My requirement is , I have a server which generates live data and writes to a log file. I need to grab the last hour data, zip it and mail it. Like if the system time is 8 o'clock in morning, then I should get data from 7 to 8 .

Comment: @user3859736  I don't want this password, just the address. Change it quick. I'll email you how I think it could be done. I'm not going to look at your code either, not unless it's really necessary.

Comment: @laune I have changed it. But please explain the scenario sir. I am in dying need.

Comment: @user3859736 See the additions to my answer.